# I can not create a SQL database in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, sqlexception

I have just installed Visual Studio 2010 and I can not make a simple database using Visual Studio. I use the following method to create the database:

[image]

The problem is when I tried to create it, I see this error:

[image]

I also see the following error when I want to access to the Asp configuration section in my Visual Studio:

> An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 5110 and the SqlException message is: The file "\MAC\HOME\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\ULTIMATEGOLDENSTUDIO1\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF" is on a network path that is not supported for database files. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. Creating the ASPNETDB_3cde4c4c17f74bb991c3d4fd2714db62 database...

Please let me know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Why did you just install VS 2010? That's six years old, and we're in rapidly changing industry. Why not use VS 2015? The error also seems pretty clear: it doesn't support a database hosted on a UNC share. Copy it to a local drive and change path accordingly.

Comment: For some reason I have to use this version of VS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running Visual Studio inside of a Parallels VM w/ your Windows User drive mapped to your host machine's shared Home folder.

Windows treats that as a network folder and, as the error message says, that isn't supported in this case.

The easiest solution would be to change the location of your Windows Profile directory so that it points to a location inside of your VM rather than a shared folder between the guest and host OSes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using the VM. Can you show me how to do that?